# How to add Oracle ons.jar to a maven project

Tags: java, oracle, maven, oracle10g

All,

Our beloved DBA's have come up with a request for us to add hibernate onsconfiguration for our Oracle JDBC connection. Now, for this to work, we need to have [Oracle provided ons.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html) in the classpath.

The current stanza we have for oracle jdbc library is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
  <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tried to look around if we can add ons.jar to maven dependency list, but could not. Could anyone please provide any inputs on how to add this?

I browsed through the ibiblio maven repository, it only has [ojdbc14](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/oracle/) and nothing for ons.jar.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ons.jar is not available in your repos, you have to download it manually and then add it to your repos.

You can add it to your local repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ons -Dversion=10.2.0.2.0 -Dfile=/path/to/file -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

If you have a remote repository, you can deploy to it with the following command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ons -Dversion=10.2.0.2.0 -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

More at: Maven - [Guide to deploying 3rd party JARs to remote repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html)

With the files installed in your repo, you can add the dependency to your project's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
 <artifactId>ons</artifactId>
 <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
 <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I guess I was not very clear in my question. We already have ojdbc14.jar added to our repo and bundled with the app. What we want to add now is ons.jar.

Comment: The ons.jar is on the page you linked. Download it manually and follow the procedures to add it to your Maven repo.

Comment: The project's dependencies are managed by Maven. My question was, "how to add it as dependency there?"

Comment: Sorry, but I am not following you. If you execute the commands above the jar will be added to your Maven repository, then you can use it as dependency to your project (just like you did with the jdbc driver).

Comment: I guess you are right. After reading your last comment I took a break, ahd some coffee, and now you sound perfectly right to me! Thanks for your inputs, i will get this jar added to our internal repository. I was confused as I could not find maven stanza for this ons jar anywhere on internet.

Comment: To sum up, my current state of mind is exactly told by : http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://images.icanhascheezburger.com/completestore/2008/7/22/icannotbraint128612173001498795.jpg&imgrefurl=http://cheezburger.com/View/819054848&h=376&w=499&sz=47&tbnid=BU42xuPQMO7htM:&tbnh=98&tbnw=130&prev=/search%3Fq%3Di%2Bhas%2Bthe%2Bdumb%26tbm%3Disch%26tbo%3Du&zoom=1&q=i+has+the+dumb&usg=__gPi8XUqdjYIWCRfc_qkl15prvKA=&sa=X&ei=tV_UTbv-DIuesQPN0ImjCQ&ved=0CC8Q9QEwAw

Comment: LOL. That can happen to anyone at some point, specially when working till late.